# Can somebody identify these characters? (Characters identified: 㸃㬹)

Tags: characters, character-identification

Could somebody help me identify these two characters?

[image]

The meaning of the first one should be "point" or something similar, the second one looks to me like a combination of 月 and 爭, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Where did you find these characters? I'm curious.

Comment: They are part of the five principles of Wing Chun that are hanging in our gym, I managed to find most of the characters but had troubles finding these two. You can se all of them [here](http://www.elywcimaa.com/wing-chun-kung-fu/index.php?id=35)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: 點] is [點](http://www.zdic.net/z/29/kx/9EDE.htm) (point). It's just written in a special "font".

[image: 㬹] is [㬹](http://www.zdic.net/z/10/kx/3B39.htm).

In 康熙字典, it is

> [image] 《集韻》《類篇》甾莖切，音爭。足跟筋也。
>   又《集韻》側杏切。義同。

Which means `足跟筋也`, i.e. tendon in the heel. It is pronounced as `zhēng`. Now it's seldom seen in Mandarin Chinese, but in spoken Cantonese, it's still widely and informally used (pronunciation `zaang1`). For example, `脚㬹`(heel), `高㬹鞋`(high-heeled shoes).

Comment: I think 㬹 is also more commonly seen written as 踭.

Comment: @Claw That's right. 踭 is included in 《新华字典》. But note that, 踭 is a new character that has appeared for less than about one hundred years. 康熙字典 has no entry for 踭 and I can't find it in any older script for it either.

Comment: In the context of Wing Chun practice, perhaps the 踭 here refers to 手踭, the elbow rather than the heel as Wing Chun places greater emphasis on upper limb techniques? And 点 here does not necessarily mean "point" but "touch", "hit" Just guessing from what little I know of Wing Chun.